# Unable to get an Epson Stylus CX3700 scanner recognised

Tags: scanner, epson, sane

### **Background:**

I've been following the help provided by the man pages of **sane** because my Epson Stylus CX3700 is not detected by **Skanlite**.
Even though the scanner is found by **sane-find-scanner** and the scanner itself is supported by the **epson2** backend (which I uncommented in **dll.conf** and whose configuration file I edited adding the line **usb 0x04b8 0x0818**, in accordance with the syntax **usb vendor product**, from the man page of **sane-usb**), when I run the command **scanimage -L** it still says that no scanners were identified (after waiting some time).

The only thing it occurs to me right now in order to solve this is that in the **epson2.conf** file the syntax for usb scanners is: **usb productID deviceID**, which seems different from the one I'm using. But so far I've not found information about what exactly those two parameters are and where to find them (I guess **productID** might be the same as **product**).

Any ideas or feedback will be greatly appreciated!

I'm using Kubuntu 16.04 LTS.